# "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" when editing a Windows 10 service

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to change the status of the `Smart Card (SCardSvr)` service from Disabled to Manual but when I click Apply I get a Windows message saying

`Cannot create a file when that file already exists`

[image]

I can't find any reference to this online or find any way of knowing which file is causing the problem.

Is there any way of knowing which file is causing the problem or a way of fixing this?

Thanks

Update:

Running `sc` from the command line gives the following

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc config SCardSvr start=auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig FAILED 183:

Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

This error may occur if another service is already using a Named
Pipe or RPC trigger for the same endpoint or interface as the
given service.
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to change the status of the service to Manual using `regedit.exe`:

http://computerstepbystep.com/smart_card_service.html

Still not sure why it would not work via the service manager.

Comment: I was also able to do it using `regedit`